# Display a pdf in a viewer on a browser after clicking on a link (html)

Tags: html, pdf

Clicking on an html link such as `<a href="Example.pdf">Example</a>` downloads the Example.pdf. Alternatively, the pdf can be permanently embedded into a viewer with a code such as `<object data="Example.pdf" type="application/pdf" title="Example" width="500" height="720"> <a href="Example.pdf">Example</a>`. However, I would rather prefer that the pdf is neither downloaded from the link, nor permanently embedded and always viewable but that one must click on a link (coded in html) to view it. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you can show a PDF:

```
<embed src="Example.pdf" width="500" height="720" type="application/pdf">
```

Then with JS you can show or hide this tag.

With Google Chrome or Android use this code:

```
<embed src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/
```

viewer?embedded=true&url=http://example.pdf" width="500" height="720">

---

UPDATE:
First introduce an ID in your tag:

```
<embed id="pdf_view" src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/
```

viewer?embedded=true&url=http://example.pdf" width="500" height="720">

Then, in your HTML create a button or in your href put an onClick.

```
<a href="Example.pdf" onClick="showPdf()">Example</a>
```

Later create a function in JS

```
<script>
function showPdf() {
    $("#pdf_view").show();
}
</script>
```

If you want to hide use:

```
$("#pdf_view").hide();
```

---

FOR DOWNLOAD PDF

```
<a href="AgustínTamayo_CV.pdf" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-3" download="AgustínTamayo_CV.pdf">Download my CV</a>
```

---

FOR SEE IN THE SAME PAGE

```
<a href="AgustínTamayo_CV.pdf" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-3">See my CV</a>
```

---

FOR SEE IN OTHER PAGE

```
<a href="AgustínTamayo_CV.pdf" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-3" target="_blank">See my CV in other page</a>
```

Comment: Your code works the same as the second code in my question. The pdf is always open. I have hundreds of pdf documents and do not want them to be all permanently open, it would be very confusing for someone to navigate the page. A pdf should be opened only when someone clicks on a link.

Comment: With this code, you can test the basic for the functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your work. The first part with the embed code and the javascript does not seem to work for me inasmuch as the pdf is always embedded on the webpage. On the other hand, omitting the javascript does not give the option to download it, which is probably something of use to some people, possibly even to me. The other code for viewing or dowloading works for me. Many thanks!

Comment: Make a div that wraps your pdf. And that div is shown only when you click the link through a js function.